# How to exclude multiple properties in FluentAssertions ShouldBeEquivalentTo()

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

Using FluentAssertions:  
I'm able to exclude a single property using ShouldBeEquivalentTo.

```
x.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(y, opts => opts.Excluding(si => !si.PropertyInfo.CanWrite));
```

But, how do I **exclude more then 1** property when using ShouldBeEquivalentTo() ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You 'll have to use a Function for that instead of an Expression.

```
x.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(y, ExcludeProperties); 

private EquivalencyAssertionOptions<xx> ExcludeProperties(EquivalencyAssertionOptions<xx> options)
    {
            options.Excluding(t => t.CeOperator);
            options.Excluding(t => t.CeOperatorName);
            options.Excluding(t => t.Status);
            options.Excluding(t => t.IsOperational);
            return options;
    }
```

Answer (score 36):

You don't necessarily need a separate method. Chain multiple calls fluently like so.

```
x.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(y, opts => opts.Excluding(si => !si.PropertyInfo.CanWrite).Excluding(si => si.SomeOtherProperty));
```